# How do I stop mousedown event from triggering in the outer element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have implemented the Angular draggable directive as provided by angular at, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. It basically just puts an event listener on the mousedown event and moves the position until a mouseup event.

```
<div class="draggable">
  <input type="text"></input>
</div>
```

The problem arises when you try to highlight the text in the input. The `div` captures the event and thinks that the mousedown is signaling the drag action instead of highlighting the text in the input.

How do I stop the mousedown event from triggering the div mousedown event when users mousedown in the input elements?

Comment: have you tried to stop the event propigation? something like this event.stopPropagation();

Comment: event.stopPropagation() is whats needed - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are looking for is `event.stopPropogation`

https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

I see that you mentioned Angular. You could try something like this.

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.bind(mouseover, function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        };
     });
```

Comment: My input (inner html element) is not a directive so I can not stop the propagation as demonstrated. However, I could capture the event by including ng-mousedown="stopEvent($event)" on the input element. Then, in my controller, the function stopEvent(event) gets called and fires event.stopPropagation() and this fixes my problem - thanks. Do all browsers handle event propagation similarly? Will the input mousedown always get called before the div mousedown?